How do I pass different data types in a variadic function, with parameter folds?
Edit: Reformatting the entire question
Making a Linked List lib, and I wanted to pass through multiple values in order to make the appending of items easier, so I created some Variadic Functions, which while testing with int values, worked well, but not for other data types.
My Linked List Code:
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename data_type>
struct _node {
    data_type data{};
    _node<data_type>* link = nullptr;
    _node(data_type value) : data(value) {}
};

template<typename s_data_type>
struct linked_list {
private:
    typedef _node<s_data_type> node;
    typedef s_data_type dt;
    int _size{};
    node* head = nullptr;
    node* last = nullptr;
public:
    template<typename ...Args> linked_list(Args ...arg) {
        (append(arg), ...); 
    }
    template<typename ...Args> void append(Args ...arg) {
        (append(arg), ...);
    }

    void append(const dt value) {
        if (this->head == nullptr) {
            head = new node(value);
            last = head;
        }
        else {
            last->link = new node(value);
            last = last->link;
        }
        _size++;
    }
    //Methods, Constructors, etc...

};
int main(){
    linked_list<string> list("123", "Such a", "Why does this work");
    list.print();
    list.append("hmm");
    list.append("wooowowow", "Please Work");
    list.append("No");
    println();
    list.print();
    return 0;
}


Now, in order to append the list, I have a append function,which works fine by itself for tested data types Float, Int, String, and also the variadic functions as long as the intiallized LL is of int type.
The first variadic constructor, works well, doesn't throw any Segmentation errors, it's the overloaded append func which throws  Segmentation faults, but it all works for Int type, which is because int is a structural class type for templates I guess? Probably not.
If Main function is written for linked_list<int>:
linked_list<int> list(1, 2, 3);
list.append(4, 5);
list.print();

Output:
{ 1 2 3 4 5 }

But for linked_list<string>, the variadic function append gives me a Segmentation Fault, which even after looking into it, I can't pinpoint why?
Segmentation Fault

Exception has occurred.: Segmentation fault

Now I have looked into parameter folds, unary, binary stuff with folding parameters, read some docs and forums, and I came up with the following code, which I can barely understand why it works.
template<typename ...args> void append(dt val, args ...arg) {
    (append(val), ((arg), ...));
}

And for the String LL initialization it produces:
{ 123 Such a Why does this work }
{ 123 Such a Why does this work hmm wooowowow No }

It skips on the "Please Work" string, and I don't know why, or even how it works TBH, but yeah, it works, barely? And for the Int section, same, doesn't append the 5 to the LL.
{ 1 2 3 4 }

My Expectations were:
For String:
{ 123 Such a Why does this work }
{ 123 Such a Why does this work hmm wooowowow Please Work No }

For Int:
{ 1 2 3 4 5 }
1 2 3 4 5


A [mre] should be provided, and a single code block instead of ten code pieces.

@3CxEZiVlQ Yeah, should have thought of it in hindsight, this is my first ever question here, so will keep that in mind next time.

You can still edit the question and add a [mcve].

"hmm" is not a std::string but a const char[4] (decaying to const char*), so append<const char*>(Args...) is a better match than append(const std::string&)

When types are all the same, std::initializer_list<dt> might be more appropriate.

After inserting std::cout to every function, it printed a lot of lines, I found your code crashed on:
list.append_values("hmm");

The variadic append function is inf recursive.
Too many recursive function call -> stack overflow -> segmentation fault.
Option1
Rename at least one of the append function to distinguish them.
#include <iostream>

template<typename data_type>
struct _node {
    data_type data{};
    _node<data_type>* link = nullptr;
    _node(data_type value) : data(value) {}
};

template<typename s_data_type>
struct linked_list {
private:
    typedef _node<s_data_type> node;
    typedef s_data_type dt;
    int _size{};
    node* head = nullptr;
    node* last = nullptr;

public:
    template<typename ...Args> linked_list(Args ...arg) {
        (append_value(arg), ...); 
    }

    void append_value(const dt value) {
        if (this->head == nullptr) {
            head = new node(value);
            last = head;
        }
        else {
            last->link = new node(value);
            last = last->link;
        }
        _size++;
    }

    template<typename ...Args> void append_values(Args ...arg) {
        (append_value(arg), ...);
    }

    void println() {
        node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            std::cout << current->data << " -> ";
            current = current->link;
        }
        std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
    }
};

void println() {
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    linked_list<std::string> list("123", "Such a", "Why does this work");
    list.println();
    list.append_values("hmm");
    list.append_values("wooowowow", "Please Work");
    list.append_values("No");
    println();
    list.println();

    return 0;
}

Option2
Use enable_if<bool, class> to conditionally enable templates.
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > 1), void>::type append(Args ...arg) {
    (append(arg), ...);
}


Yeah, that does work, just having it as another function, another thing which I tried and worked, is just doing, append(val); append(arg....),  where val is passed in as dt val parameter for the variadic function.

Adding to cpprust's answer regarding the infinite recursion variadic function, here are a few additional question-marks regarding your code, which are too much for a comment:

Making a Linked List lib


Are you sure you need such a library?
Have you considered all FOSS C++ libraries offering linked lists? What about, specifically, the standard library?


using namespace std;

You've made using your library somewhat dangerous and possibly name-clashing, by using namespace std globally.

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

You're relying on non-standard, GCC-specific (or even GCC-version-specific) include files. You should avoid this...

I wanted to pass through multiple values in order to make the appending of items easier

Sometimes, "easier" is actually "harder", and more complex; and I believe that's the case with your append() method...
template<typename ...Args> append(Args ...arg);


You should probably not allow appending values of any type; this is a list of elements of type data_type, after all.
A call such as my_list.append(foo, bar) is confusing:

Do both parameters mean the same thing?
In what order will they be appended?
Or - is there a construction of a more complex object for the multiple arguments?


It is also confusing as it diverges from the convention of the standard containers, such as `std::list.

The same goes for your constructor; why should the constructor be adding elements? It is not trivial to guess that's what the constructor parameters mean.
If someone wants to insert many elements into your list - they'll use a loop.

struct _node

You've made this an outer type rather an inner type of the node - already suspect, unless you can justify it as a class unto its own. Moreover, you've named it starting with _, which, while not reserved, is pretty close to that; so it's better to avoid such names unless you have a very good reason to use them.

As @cpprust already said the segmentation fault is a result of stack overflow.

At first, you're trying to construct an object of a new linked_list<std::string> type, that causes implicit instantiation of the linked_list template class, and you get the linked_list<std::string> class.
Then implicit instantiation of the template constructor takes place by calling it, and you get a constructor with three const char* type parameters, because you pass string literals to the constructor by value and they decay from const char[N] to the pointer type.
In the constructor, three append methods must be called one by one, and the compiler is trying to figure out what the first method should be called. There are a few candidates: the append(std::string), which actually does all useful work, and the append template method, whose instantiation gives a new append(const char*) method. As far as I remember, the better viable function is a function with the most accurate match, so append(const char*) is chosen.
The append(const char*) called another append(const char*) and so forth. The append(std::string) is never being reached. The stack overflows.

A naive solution is to use the string literal operator everywhere:
using namespace std::string_literals;

linked_list<std::string> list("123"s, "Such a"s, "Why does this work"s);
list.print();
list.append("hmm"s);
list.append("wooowowow"s, "Please Work"s);
list.append("No"s);
list.print();

You can also rename your method as @cpprust suggested.
But also you can make your append(const dt value) a template (a non-variadic template is more specialized than a variadic template):
template<typename T>
void append(T value) {
  static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<dt, T>);
  // your code
}

The static assert thing won't let anyone pass objects, from which dt can't be constructed, to the constructor.
Also I'd not recommend passing by value in your case, but that's not the current subject.
